# Can i get an additional button called view in admins panel?

Tags: django, python-2.7, django-admin

[image]

I want VIEW Button after Add button.Is this possible?I have already created a view permission, but this doesn't work. what to do now?
If this is possible please let me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change it...

create template folder and inside create admin folder after that copy  index.html file from `django/contrib/admin/templates/admin`

```
your-project
|
|__app1
|
|__app2
|
|__template
   |
   |__admin
      |
      |__index.html
```

Please give the exact path of your virtualenv...

```
cp ../venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/admin/templates/admin/index.html template/admin/
```

And now you can change anything you want...

**Note**: And one more thing do not forgot to update settings.TEMPLATES like this

```
'DIRS': [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'templates'),
],
```

Comment: Got view there but how can i give functionality like other two has?

Comment: I think you didn't get me.
If i click on add button it takes me to add info page.
like wise  if i click view i want to get all the info as read only fields.